# How to retrieve date from a Rundeck job

Tags: rundeck

I'm trying to achieve something like this in a rundeck 2.6 job:

`touch /foo/bar/${DATE:MM/dd/yyyy}-baz`

but it doesn't work properly and the date is not interpreted at all. Is there a proper way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this bash script :

```
#!/bin/bash
touch /foo/bar/`date "+%m/%d/%Y"`-baz
```

The backquotes act as [command substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html) and replace the output of the [`date`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/date.1.html) command in the [`touch`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/touch.1.html) command.

According to the [date man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/date.1.html) :

> An operand with a leading plus (`+') sign signals a user-defined format string which
>        specifies the format in which to display the date and time.  The format string may contain any of the conversion specifications described in the [strftime(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html) manual page, as
>        well as any arbitrary text.

The date format string use the following [conversion specifier character](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html) :

> - **%m**     The month as a decimal number (range 01 to 12).  (Calculated
>               from tm_mon.)
> - **%d**     The day of the month as a decimal number (range 01 to 31).
>               (Calculated from tm_mday.)
> - **%Y**     The year as a decimal number including the century.
>               (Calculated from tm_year)

Answer (score 0):

You can also define an option that uses that date format specifier. 
Set the default value of the option to use the specifier. Eg:

```
<option name="date" value="${DATE:MM/dd/yyyy}-baz" />
```

Inside your step reference the ${option.date}.